# why python logging RotatingFileHandler lost records when used in multiple processes?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

Recently I've realize that my application generate less log records than I expected. After some experiments I've found that problem is in  RotatingFileHandler and multiprocessing.

```
import logging
from logging import handlers
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os


log_file_name = 'log.txt'
def make_logger():
    logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    current_handler_names = {handler.name for handler in logger.handlers}
    handler_name = 'my_handler'
    if handler_name in current_handler_names:
        return logger

    handler = handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
        log_file_name, maxBytes=10 * 2 ** 10, backupCount=0)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler.set_name(handler_name)

    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger



def f(x):
    logger = make_logger()
    logger.info('hey %s' % x)


if os.path.exists(log_file_name):
    os.unlink(log_file_name)

p = Pool(processes=30)
N = 1000
p.map(f, range(N))
with open(log_file_name, 'r') as f:
    print 'expected: %s, real: %s' % (N, f.read().count('hey'))
```

Output:

```
$ python main.py
expected: 1000, real: 943
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 7):

As it is [well explained](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes),

> Although logging is thread-safe, and logging to a single file from multiple threads in a single process is supported, logging to a single file from multiple processes is not supported

In a few words, `RotatingFileHandler` simply closes and deletes the file from one process, then opens a new file. But other processes don't know about a new file descriptor and see that previous have been closed. Only the process who managed to rotate the file first continues logging.

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48668567/494631) to the similar question I've proposed to use `logrotate` daemon to rotate files aside of these processes. It *does not* close the file descriptor, but just *truncates* the file. Thus file remains the same and other processes can continue logging.

Comment: Thank you for link! 

But your explanation seems wrong to me, because on my computer snippet shows divergent results with pretty small N and big maxBytes value thus there is no rollover during snippet execution